# Is there any point in leveling up the Monkey King past level 3?

Tags: monkey-evolution, tapps-games

In Tapps games' [Monkey Evolution](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.tapps.monkeyevolution), you get the Monkey King by combining two Belzebaboons, and each time after that you combine two Belzebaboons to level him up. At level 3 you can re-create the work, gaining Suns and Diamonds in exchange for starting back at the Baby Monkey level.

You can keep leveling the Monkey King past level 3 instead of recreating the world. Is there any benefit or point in doing so?

Answer (score -1):

If you level him up more, he simply earns more.